# HTML and Flex Focus Problem

Tags: html, apache-flex

I have a web page which has a SWF file embeded. I have an issue with the focus.

Click on a HTML Text Field and Click on a Flex  Field. 
Begin to type a text.

Expected Result is the entered text should go in the Flex TextInput field but the
actual Result is it goes into HTML text field.

Comment: Sounds strange. In what browsers? Can you show a live example?

Comment: The application is an internal app and I do not have another live example. It is happening in IE 7 but not in IE8.

Comment: seems to be a browser bug. Maybe you can "workaround" it with a bit of javascript!?

Answer (score 0):

to me it sounds like something related to wmode in the embedding code, I would try to play around with that, I have found flash to be very problematic when replacing between wmodes.

Comment: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-12377 is the same bug which was filed and that has a live example mentioned. The Jira was closed without any resolution though.